# How with PHP parse entity content through to simple xml string ID attributes

Tags: php, xml-parsing, simplexml

Below is the current outcome of “$image1” entity that provides a live URL xml feed

```
$output .= "<image>".$image1."</image>\n";
```

Below is my working ID attributes that are required for the content (URL) above entity

```
$output .= $string = <<<XML
<images>
     <image id='1'><url></url></image>
    </images> 
  XML;
```

This code produces the following XML feed:

```
<root>
 <property>
      <images>
            <image id='1'><url> </url></image>
       </images>
```

Please my question is what PHP code! Array! is required to have the contents $image1 (URL) now working within the url tags of the xml string?

Please my Desired outcome is witin my current document :

```
    <root>
        <property>
         <images>
              <image id='1'><url>$image1(url required from this entity as above)/url>   </image>
    </images>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [DOMDocument](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php) like this:

```
$document = new DOMDocument();

$images = $document->createElement('images');
$image = $document->createElement('image');
$url = $document->createElement('url', 'www.mydomain.com');

$document->appendChild($images);
$images->appendChild($image);
$image->setAttribute('id', 1);
$image->appendChild($url);

print $document->saveXML();
// or
$document->save("/path/to/file.xml");
```